# Is there any way for an Android layout to know when it's children are drawing?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view

Basically, I'm trying to figure out if there's any way for a parent layout to tell when a child has invalidated/is drawing/has changed.

So far, I've tried looking at almost all methods with 'draw' in them (i.e. onDraw, dispatchDraw, draw, etc) and none of them seem to fire if a child is quietly updating itself.

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want to set up a `ViewTreeObserver`:
http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ViewTreeObserver.html

Comment: Thanks!

I tried it out, and found that OnPreDrawListener works as I would expect (every time a child/grandchild is about to draw anything it fires). Strangely, OnDrawListener never seemed to fire. Just a heads up to anybody who sees this in the future!

Comment: Where are you trying to add the OnDrawListener. You cannot add it from an onDraw method call.

Comment: I'm adding it at the constructor. CustomLayout implements OnPreDrawlistener and OnDrawListener.


 public CustomLayout(Context context) {
  super(context);
  getViewTreeObserver().addOnPreDrawListener(this);
  getViewTreeObserver().addOnDrawListener(this);
 }

Comment: I also don't see onDrawListener firing, which is a bummer because I'm using a TextureView that does not let me override onDraw. My workaround is to use `addOnGlobalLayoutListener`, which seems to fire immediately *before* my view's draw finishes.

Comment: thanks for confirming `OnDrawListener` not calling... it is strange